# using vba to Setting calculated values to bookmarks in a Word Document

Tags: java, excel, vba, ms-word

Take a look at this vba code; this vba code currently copies a value from cell E40 and paste it at its specific bookmark location "fundedRatio" in a word template. What i want to do is access the newly calculated value in val and set it to the specific bookmark "fundedRatio". How do i do this in vba? In Java GUI application would be something like this fundedRatio.setText(val); But how do i do this in vba?

```
 DIM gfy as Double
 gfy = Sheets("Income & Expenditure Analysis").Range("E40").Copy
 val = gfy*2
 myDoc.Bookmarks("fundedRatio").Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False,    
DataType:=wdPasteText
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Dim gfy as Double
Dim val As Double
gfy = Sheets("Income & Expenditure Analysis").Range("E40").Value 'no copy here
val = gfy*2
myDoc.Bookmarks("fundedRatio").Range.Text = val
```